# Excel VBA data manipulation

Tags: vba, excel

My problem might be simple but i have been stuck on it for a while. I have a list of accounts in column B (XXXXXX). Then in column D i have a quantity of contracts traded. In the column E i have the prices of those contracts. The column next to it has the name of the product traded.

The way i get the raw data i sometimes get a trade split in 2 parts. For example i might have on one row for the same (column B) account XXXXXX , QTY(Column D) 2 and Price(column E) 5.23$ and security(column F) NKE. In the next row i have the same account XXXXX , QTY is 3 , Price is same and the security is same. I want something that will loop through the entire data and add the QTY to 5 and keep everything else the same. So at the end i should have one row with with account XXXXXX with QTY 5 Price 5.23$ and Security NKE. I have tried pivot tables but it adds the price of the security to 10.46$ and that messes up calculations. I cannot figure what sort of a macro i should use. Can someone please help. I am posting a picture to help understand the problem. THanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Zz5.png)

Comment: Please, show us what have try so far.

Comment: Answers can differ depending on the version of Excel. You should provide the version of Excel you're using.

Comment: Changing the aggregate calculation in your pivot table to `Average` instead of `Sum` for the price will work for your specific example, but won't if each line has a different price. Which price should you choose if the prices vary between the same securities? Also, if you aren't using Ms Access, please remove the tag.

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something in the question, but why not:

 - insert a new column next to d with a formula in cell e2 like =d2+5
 - dclick the bottom right corner of the selection to fill it down

Comment: Can a moderator please repost the deleted macro on this post. Thanks.

Comment: @ Andy G. Please get me the deleted post from yesterday

Answer (score 1):

A pivot should show you what you want. Don't put *Price* in VALUES. *Account*, *Security* and *Price* can go in ROWS then *Sum of Quantity* in VALUES. That should give you the breakdown you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that and it solved the issue. However it took the  average of other prices which i wanted to keep unique. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose the most unique column (probably F).
2. Filter your data by this column.
3. Make an infinite loop. Inside the loop:

   - declare a variable for row number
   - check if the current row has the same value in column F as the row below
   - if yes, add quantities in first row and delete second row
   - if no, add one to row number and check if there is something in the current row. If no, exit the loop.

Comment: Did you post that macro earlier? If yes, can you repost? Thanks.

Comment: @Masood No, I didn't. But it's an easy one.

Answer (score 0):

To the person who posted a macro. Can you please repost? I was just writing a note to you and I see you deleted the comment